# Как запретить выбор более одного чекбоска в раскрывающемся списке?

Tags: flutter, dart

В приложении есть список с раскрывающимися элементами, как показано на рисунке:

[image: Раскрывающийся список с чекбоксами]
Дело в том, что по бизнес-логике нельзя в одном из списков выбирать более одного чекбокса. Каким образом можно сделать такое условие?

Вот код класса, которые формирует раскрывающийся список:

```
class _EntryItemState extends State<EntryItem> {
  //TODO: Сделать условие для выбора только ОДНОГО чекбокса

  Entry entry;
  _EntryItemState(Entry entry){
    this.entry = entry;
  }

  Widget _buildTiles(Entry root) {
    if (root.children.isEmpty)
      return new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new CheckboxListTile(
            title: new Text(
              root.title,
              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
            ),
            value: root.isChecked,
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                root.isChecked = value;
                charactToList(root);
              });
            },
          ),
          new Divider(height: 16.0, indent: 0.0),
        ],
      );
//      return new Divider();
    return new ExpansionTile(
      key: new PageStorageKey<Entry>(root),
      title: new Text(root.title),
      children: root.children.map(_buildTiles).toList()
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildTiles(entry);
  }
  void charactToList (Entry root){
    if(root.isChecked){
      character.add(root.title);
    }
    if(!root.isChecked){
      character.remove(root.title);
    }
  }
}
```

А вот код класса объекта Entry:

```
class Entry {
  Entry(this.isChecked, this.title, [this.children = const <Entry>[]]);
  final String title;
  List<Entry> children;
  bool isChecked;
}
```

И ниже пример списка объектов:
[image: Список объектов]

Comment: Радиобаттон придуман как раз для этого.

Comment: не подходит, когда столько уровней вложений объектов и нужно иметь не более одного выбора для каждого из самых нижних уровней

Comment: Чем именно не подходит?

Comment: Если использую Radio у меня будет возможность выбора всего одного элемента, а мне нужно иметь возможность выбрать 1-16 элементов списка. Возможно я не могу просто разобраться, не спорю. Поэтому и спрашиваю. Вы подсказали, я попробовал и не получается пока

Comment: Радиокнопки объединяются в группы. В каждой группе можно будет выбрать только один элемент. Вам нужно создать отдельную группу радиокнопкок для каждой подкатегории, а не одну единственную вообще для всех (как вы скорее все сделали, просто заменив в коде одно на другое).

Comment: да, именно так и сделал )) спасибо, буду разбираться!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79549/discussion-between--and-).

Comment: Сделай checkbox свойствами radio button.
Вот пример https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839884/make-checkbox-behave-like-radio-buttons-with-javascript

Comment: я не силен в js поэтому не понимаю, как это сделать в flutter....